# Finding by name while ignoring white space in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following action in my tags controller:
(`params[:q]` comes from this plugin http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

```
  def index
    @tags = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    results = @tags.map(&:attributes)
    @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:q])
    if @tag.blank?
      results << {:name => "Add: #{params[:q]}", :id => "CREATE_#{params[:q]}_END"}
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => results }
    end
  end
```

This part:

```
  @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:q])
  if @tag.blank?
    results << {:name => "Add: #{params[:q]}", :id => "CREATE_#{params[:q]}_END"}
  end
```

Makes the line of code above to only trigger if the current tag name doesn't exist.

The problem is that if the user types something like this in the input:

```
"programming " <- a trailing white space
" programming" <- a trailing white space
```

the code is executed anyway, since the trailing spaces makes Rails think that it is a new name.

what's the best way of dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
params[:q].delete!(' ')
@tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:q])
if @tag.blank?
  results << {:name => "Add: #{params[:q]}", :id => "CREATE_#{params[:q]}_END"}
end
```

Note the first line will delete all spaces in the params[:q]. If this is not what you want, you can first duplicate the variable with *dup* method

Comment: hey, it worked. But I'm curious, why didn't you use `strip` instead?

Comment: Because I thought you wanted to remove whitespace even if the user types some tag like ` program ming`

Answer (score 1):

Strip whitespace by calling `String#strip` - which strips all leading & trailing whitespace:

```
" programming ".strip 
=> "programming"
```

Comment: I'm aware of `strip`. I just don't know how to use it with the `find_by_name` part.